# What's the best way to insert the number of lines in the file at the beginning of the file in C?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have a file in which few lines are being dumped. I want to post process the file and insert a header at the beginning of this file. The header is basically the number of lines in the file before inserting the header. I need to write this in C preferable irrespective of the platform. I was thinking of using system command in C code as follows to calculate  the number of lines in the file:

```
int header = system("wc -l myfile");
```

save header in the temp file;
append myfile in temp file;
replace or move tempfile with myfile

Looking for a better way.

Comment: Write a scratch line of several spaces, process the file and count the lines, rewind the and overwrite the scratch space with the line count?

Comment: *I need to write this in C preferable irrespective of the platform* - `wc` is a Linux command.

Comment: since `system()` and `wc` are related to linux you cannot make them as _irrespective of platform_

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware that wc and system are linux commands. It's preferable that the code is platform independent but as of now linux is primary requirement so wc works for me.

Comment: In this case the easiest and "Linux platform independent" way would be to write a shell script. It will be even more portable between Linux systems than a C program.

Comment: Often, the best way to do something is to reconsider the problem space.  It is often useful to have file metadata stored in a header, but doing so limits the usefulness of the file format. Having a header which simply contains the number of lines in the file is generally not more useful than the limitations it imposes. In other words, the best way to do this is to not do it at all.  Instead, ensure that the consumers can handle the input data without knowing in advance how many lines of input will be given.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  We put the number of lines of the file at the top of the file once (long ago) because every so often ftp would only transfer half the file.  Then it would look valid to the consumer but wouldn't contain all of it.

Comment: irrespective of the platform --> platform independent

Comment: Simple implementation of `wc` command [A Source of the wc command](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/html_node/Source-of-wc-command.html)
Use `total_lcount` as lines of file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `diff` ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252927/what-do-the-numbers-in-the-line-mean-in-output-of-diff ) then you know which lines were dumped

To write text to the begin of a file use shell commands like `sed -i '1s/^/task goes here\n/' todo.txt` (https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash), in C you can execute shell commands using `sh` or `system` depends if the shell command is built-in.

If you want this platform independent you have to count the lines in C like in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-count-number-lines-file/

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward option is to do the postprocessing and line counting in one pass (counting the number of lines *written* to a temporary file), then creating an another temporary file but this time in the same directory as the target file, writing the header to the latter temporary file, copying the contents of the first temporary file to the latter temporary file, removing the first temporary file, and finally renaming the latter temporary file as the final file.

This would be very simple to do using POSIX C `getline()` (which is included in standard C libraries in Linux, BSDs, and Mac OS), but it is not available on Windows.  We'd need to first write a wrapper function, that on non-Windows systems uses POSIX `getline()` to read unlimited-length lines; and uses `fgetc()` or some other function to implement same/similar function Windows.

Another approach would be to read the file using `fread()` into a dynamically allocated buffer, and call a callback/filtering function for each line read.  This approach has the benefit of being able to support any newline encoding (NUL, LF, CR, LF CR, or CR LF) and minimizing buffer copies, but the downside of being unfamiliar approach to many programmers.

Consider the following example implementation of `for_each_line()`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    NEWLINE_INVALID = -1,   /* Invalid NEWLINE_ enum value */
    NEWLINE_NONE = 0,       /* No newline at end of line; ended at end of stream */
    NEWLINE_CR   = 1,       /* "\r" */
    NEWLINE_LF   = 2,       /* "\n" */
    NEWLINE_CRLF = 3,       /* "\r\n" */
    NEWLINE_LFCR = 4,       /* "\n\r" */
    NEWLINE_NUL  = 5        /* "", or '\0', */
} newline_type;


int for_each_line(FILE *source,
                  int (*filter)(char *line, size_t len, void *context),
                  void *context)
{
    char    *data = NULL;   /* source data buffer */
    size_t   size = 0;      /* size of source data buffer in chars */
    size_t   head = 0;      /* start of next line to pass to filter */
    size_t   tail = 0;      /* next char to read into buffer */

    int      newline = NEWLINE_INVALID;

    /* Neither source nor filter can be NULL. */
    if (!source || !filter)
        return -1;  /* -1: Invalid parameters */

    /* source stream should not be in error state. */
    if (ferror(source))
        return -2;  /* -2: Error reading source. */

    while (1) {
        size_t  next = head;
        size_t  n;
        int     retval;

        /* Check if we have a complete line to supply to filter. */
        if (tail > head) {
            /* To be able to safely use strcspn(), we need a terminating nul at end of buffer. */
            data[tail] = '\0';

            /* Find the first occurrence of any newline character. */
            n = strcspn(data + head, "\r\n");
            if (n < tail - head) {
                /* Found, and it wasn't the nul we added. */
                if (data[head + n] == '\r') {
                    /* CR or CR LF */
                    if (data[head + n + 1] == '\n') {
                        newline = NEWLINE_CRLF;
                        next = head + n + 2;
                    } else {
                        newline = NEWLINE_CR;
                        next = head + n + 1;
                    }
                } else
                if (data[head + n] == '\n') {
                    /* LF or LF CR */
                    if (data[head + n + 1] == '\r') {
                        newline = NEWLINE_LFCR;
                        next = head + n + 2;
                    } else {
                        newline = NEWLINE_LF;
                        next = head + n + 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    /* Must have been NUL */
                    newline = NEWLINE_NUL;
                    next = head + n + 1;
                }

                /* Note: A two-character newline might have been split at the end of a buffer,
                         so at this point, 'newline' is *tentative*, not exact. */
                if (newline != NEWLINE_INVALID) {
                    /* We replace the newline with end-of-string NUL mark. */
                    data[head + n] = '\0';
                    retval = filter(data + head, n, context);
                    if (retval) {
                        free(data);
                        return retval;
                    }
                    head = next;

                    /* Check for next line, before trying to refill the buffer. */
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        /* If the buffer is at least half full, move the data to beginning of buffer. */
        if (head >= tail) {
            /* Buffer is completely empty. */
            head = 0;
            tail = 0;
        } else
        if (head > 0 && tail >= size / 2) {
            /* Buffer is at least half full, and not aligned at start of buffer. Move. */
            tail -= head;
            memmove(data, data + head, tail);
            head = 0;
        }

        /* Need to grow the buffer? */
        if (tail + 2 >= size) {
            /* TODO:  Improve on this linear growth policy. */
            const size_t  new_size = (tail | 4095) + 4097 - 32;
            char         *new_data;

            new_data = realloc(data, new_size);
            if (!new_data) {
                free(data);
                return -3;  /* Not enough memory. */
            }
            data = new_data;
            size = new_size;
        }

        /* Read some data into the buffer. */
        n = fread(data + tail, 1, size - tail - 1, source);
        if (n > 0) {
            tail += n;

            /* Consume partial newline, since now we know we can. */
            if (newline == NEWLINE_CR && data[head] == '\n') {
                newline = NEWLINE_CRLF;
                head++;
            } else
            if (newline == NEWLINE_LF && data[head] == '\r') {
                newline = NEWLINE_LFCR;
                head++;
            }

        } else
        if (ferror(source)) {
            free(data);
            return -2;  /* Error reading source. */
        } else {
            /* End of input. */
            if (tail > head) {
                data[tail] = '\0';
                retval = filter(data + head, tail - head, context);
                free(data);
                return retval;
            } else {
                free(data);  /* Note: free(NULL) is safe. */
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    /* Execution never reaches here. */
}

struct context {
    FILE               *out;
    const char         *newline;
    unsigned long long  lines;
};

static int do_copy_count_lines(char *line, size_t len, void *ctxptr)
{
    struct context *const ctx = ctxptr;

    (void)len;  /* Silence warning about unused parameter 'len'. Does nothing. */

    fputs(line, ctx->out);
    fputs(ctx->newline, ctx->out);
    ctx->lines++;

    return ferror(ctx->out);
}

int copy_count_lines(FILE *source, FILE *target, unsigned long long *linecount)
{
    struct context  ctx;
    int             retval;

    if (!source || !target)
        return -1;  /* Invalid parameters */

    ctx.out = target;
    ctx.newline = "\n";
    ctx.lines = 0;

    retval = for_each_line(source, do_copy_count_lines, &ctx);

    if (linecount)
        *linecount = ctx.lines;

    return retval;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long  count = 0;
    int                 err;

    err = copy_count_lines(stdin, stdout, &count);
    if (err) {
        fflush(stdout);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed: for_each_line() returned %d.\n", err);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "Copied %llu lines from standard input to standard output.\n", count);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above example program simply reads from standard input, writing the lines (replacing any newline convention with the default newline convention for standard output), and the number of lines copied to standard error.

Because this uses `fread()`, it is very fast, but not suitable for interactive input (from terminals or terminal emulators), because it reads the input in large-ish blocks.

A variant that uses `fgetc()` is easy to implement, well suited for interactive input, but because of the large number of function calls, is somewhat slower.
Here is an example variant for use with wide character strings.  (Do note that Windows' wide character support may be broken; the following is strictly C standard compliant code.)

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Only EDOM, EILSEQ, and ERANGE are guaranteed to be known,
   so errno constants may need to be mapped. */

/* getline(): End of stream */
#ifndef  WGETLINE_EOF
#define  WGETLINE_EOF  0
#endif

/* getline(): Invalid parameters */
#ifndef  WGETLINE_EINVAL
#ifdef   EINVAL
#define  WGETLINE_EINVAL  EINVAL
#else
#define  WGETLINE_EINVAL  EILSEQ
#endif
#endif

/* getline(): Not enough memory */
#ifndef  WGETLINE_ENOMEM
#ifdef   ENOMEM
#define  WGETLINE_ENOMEM  ENOMEM
#else
#define  WGETLINE_ENOMEM  ERANGE
#endif
#endif

/* getline(): Read error */
#ifndef  WGETLINE_EIO
#ifdef   EIO
#define  WGETLINE_EIO  EIO
#else
#define  WGETLINE_EIO  EDOM
#endif
#endif


size_t wgetline(wchar_t **lineptr, size_t *sizeptr, FILE *handle)
{
    if (!lineptr || !sizeptr || !handle) {
        errno = WGETLINE_EINVAL;
        return 0;
    } else
    if (ferror(handle)) {
        errno = WGETLINE_EIO;
        return 0;
    } else
    if (feof(handle)) {
        errno = WGETLINE_EOF;
        return 0;
    }

    wchar_t *line = *lineptr;
    size_t   size = *sizeptr;
    size_t   used =  0;
    wint_t   wc;

    if (!size)
        line = NULL;

    while (1) {

        /* Make sure there are is room for at least three wide chars in the buffer. */
        if (used + 3 > size) {
            /* TODO: Better buffer growth policy? size is in wchar_t's. */
            size = (used | 1023) + 1025 - 16;
            line = realloc(line, size * sizeof line[0]);  /* realloc(NULL, ..) is safe. */
            if (!line) {
                errno = WGETLINE_ENOMEM;
                return 0;
            }
            *lineptr = line;
            *sizeptr = size;
        }

        wc = getwc(handle);
        if (wc == WEOF) {
            line[used] = L'\0';
            if (!used)
                errno = WGETLINE_EOF;
            return used;
        } else {
            line[used++] = wc;
            if (wc == L'\n') {
                line[used] = L'\0';
                return used;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Never reached. */
}

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t  *line = NULL;
    size_t    size = 0;
    size_t    len;

    unsigned long long  lines = 0uLL, wchars = 0uLL;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    if (fwide(stdin, 1) != 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Your C library or locale does not support wide character standard input.\n");
    if (fwide(stdout, 1) != 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Your C library or locale does not support wide character standard output.\n");

    while (1) {

        len = wgetline(&line, &size, stdin);
        if (!len)
            break;

        lines++;
        wchars += len;

        fputws(line, stdout);
    }

    if (ferror(stdin) || !feof(stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from standard input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fflush(stdout);
    if (ferror(stdout)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to standard output.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Copied %llu lines (%llu wide characters).\n", lines, wchars);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To give you an idea on how performant these are, `time wc -l /usr/share/dict/american-english` takes 5ms real time on my system; `time ./ex1 < /usr/share/dict/american-english > /dev/null` takes 12ms; and `time ./ex2 < /usr/share/dict/american-english > /dev/null` takes 85ms.  All three agree it has 102,305 lines. It has 971,304 wide characters, using UTF-8 character set (with file size 971,578 bytes).